# Collection of object with self recursive type in scala

Tags: scala, recursive-type

```
trait Node[N<:Node[N]] { self:N =>
}

trait A extends Node[A]

trait B {
  def list:List[Node[_]]

  def as:List[A] = list.collect { case x:A => x }
}
```

I'm having some trouble with using self recursive type in collections. In this example, the compiler gives the error

```
 def as = list.collect { case x:A => x }
                       ^
type arguments [_$1] do not conform to trait Node's type parameter bounds [N <: Node[N]]
```

because wildcard in List[Node[_]] does not conform the type bound. Is there any proper way of specifying wildcard type to recursive bound?
One workaround is

```
  def as = {
    list match {
      case list:List[Node[n]] => list.collect { case x:A => x }
    }
  }
```

which is quite ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can solve this with an existential

```
trait Node[N<:Node[N]] { self:N =>
}

trait A extends Node[A]

trait B {
  def list:List[X forSome {type X <: Node[X]}]

  def as:List[A] = list.collect { case x:A => x }
}
```

just a fair warning `forSome` is going to be removed from scala at some point. Can you tell us more about what you're trying to do? mayber there's a more elegant way to do this

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I want. I use self recursive function so node can define functions that return subtype N. But if I have collection of Node[_] it would lose the type parameter. Node[_<:Node[_]] is not perfect either. It seems weird that given there's a lower bound on N, Node[_] does not infer the wildcard type already satisfy that bound.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
trait B {
  def list: List[_ <: Node[_]]

  def as:List[A] = list.collect { case x:A => x }
}
```